# How try and catch redirect to error page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

Good morning,

I have a registration form which adds the user to the system. For example when the admin enters a letter instead of a date in the date of birth, an exception occurs. I did the following code in the web.config:

"customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx""

How the try and catch function will redirect the admin to the error.aspx when the error occurs?

Comment: isnt it easier to make it failsafe? (if dateofbirth != the form of a DateTime dont add.)

Comment: rethrow the exception in catch block

Answer (score 1):

Since you have captured this exception, it will not redirect to the error page. If you want to do so, please try to rethrow the exception.

```
catch (Exception)
{
   // your custom code
   throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to catch the exception then do a manual redirect (Response.Redirect) to your error page. You can pass the exception to your error page in a session variable or application variable.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you do something, the admin page will **NOT** redirect to error.aspx if you catch the exception yourself.

it will only redirect for unhandled exceptions.

**update**
From your comments, it seems you are better of creating some kind of validation on your page together with a validationsummary instead of relying on a redirect to the Error page. You want two things that cannot go together.

```
<asp:CompareValidator 
    id="dateValidator" runat="server"  
    Type="Date" 
    Operator="DataTypeCheck" 
    ControlToValidate="txtDatecompleted"  
    ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date."> 
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: how can I redirect the admin to the error page without a try and catch?

Comment: the system crashes and the error page appears. I don't want the system to crash :P

Comment: well of course, otherwise you are not redirected. See my update for what I think is a better approach for you